# Mongodb:unwind result after Populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

i want to unwind populate result **barId** .is this possible. i dont want to use $lookup because of perfromce issue.My query part is given below:

```
const details = await this.itemOrder
                    .find(queryFind,fetchData[0].itemOrder)
                    .lean()
                    .populate('itemOrdered',fetchData[1].itemOrdered, null, { sort: { 'alcoholName': 1 } })
                    .populate('barId',fetchData[2].userDetails)
                    .skip((Number(process.env.PERPAGELIMIT ) * pageNo) - Number(process.env.PERPAGELIMIT ))
                    .limit(Number(process.env.PERPAGELIMIT ))
                    .sort([['orderDate', -1]]);
    return details;
```

after executing this, my result is :

```
 [
   {
  "_id": "5e7ee53425592a2c040891b8",
  "grantTotal": 0,
  "customerName": "kiran",
  "barId": {
    "address": "address1,address2"
  }...
]
```

but my expected result is

```
[
   {
  "_id": "5e7ee53425592a2c040891b8",
  "grantTotal": 0,
  "customerName": "kiran",
  "barId": "address1,address2"
  ...
]
```

Comment: any help????????

Comment: I would recommend you to go through `MongoDB aggregate` and `lookup` to merger `users` and `itemOrder` collection  [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/]

Comment: but there will be performance issue when using $lookup?